# Desktop mail client with support for GMail search?

Tags: search, gmail

I use GMail as my primary mail service, and maily use the default web interface. I would like to use a native mail application (e.g. OS X Mail.app), because I like the feel and integration that a native desktop client offers. But I also use GMail's search functionality quite frequently.

So is there any way to set up a desktop mail client for GMail in such a way that I still have a powerful mail search option available?

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use Outlook, there is [Xobni](http://www.xobni.com/) which offers slightly better then gmail search . Shows the contacts and breaks down all attachments sent and conversations.

Comment: I have tried Xobni in combination with my work setup (Outlook + Exchange), but wasn't really impressed. Besides, this would only be able to search the mails that are synchronized and stored locally, right? I would like to be able to search *all* mail, just like GMail's web search offers.